# Beta and normal CDF mixture

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, integral

Is it possible to evaluate the following integrals?

$\int_0^1 y^{m-1}(1-y)^{n-1}\Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(y)+\mu\right)dy$, where $m, n, \mu$ are constants and $\Phi(.)$ is the normal CDF

Comment: This is essentially the same question as the recently closed [Expectation or integration of the normal pdf](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213561/6633).